# Loop thru each line using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to read a file - sample.txt, take the value (line by line) and change to that corresponding value's folder using a loop.

```
sample.txt

foo
bar
alpha
bravo
..
..
```

Eg: D:\myProject\myWork\foo\myFiles
     D:\myProject\myWork\bar\somenewFolder

What I came up with

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (sample.txt) do (
 set value=%%x
 set folder=D:\myProject\myWork\%value%\somenewFolder
 echo %folder%
 )
```

but the folder's value is empty. I'm not sure where I have went wrong. Any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (sample.txt) do (
 set "value=%%x"
 set folder=D:\myProject\myWork\!value!\somenewFolder
 echo !folder!
 )
```

Comment: try with `echo  "%del_folder%\%%a"` to see if the path is correct and need to be changed.

Comment: `"!del_folder!\%%a"` did the trick, thanks for looking into it.